# python: цикл for

Tags: python, циклы

У меня есть входное значение duration, например, секунда. Из нее надо взять только первую букву С.

```
dur_arr = ['с', 'м', 'ч', 'д']

    for t in duration:
        # print(t)
        if t in dur_arr:
```

Мне надо, чтобы `for t in duration` выполнила цикл 1 раз, чтобы из всего слова взять только одну букву, но у меня не выходит.

Comment: О чем этот заголовок?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`из всего слова взять только одну букву`
Для этого не нужен цикл, просто возьмите один нужный символ строки.
Пример для первого символа:

```
duration = 'секунда'
print(duration[0])
```

Comment: извините, вы меня не так поняли, из-за того, что я вырвал код из контекста. У меня есть входное значение duration, например, секунда. Из нее надо взять только первую букву С.

Comment: Покажите задание duration

Comment: async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, duration: str, *, reason='Отсутствует'):

Comment: `duration[0]` .

Comment: спасибо большое, если честно, не знал, что со строки можно взять определенную букву.

Answer (score 0):

```
duration = 'секунда'
index = duration.find("с")
print(duration[index])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: весь этот код можно заменить на ``print("с")``. ведь он ищет позицию, на которой находится буква "с", а потом печатает букву, которая находится на той позиции. И буква эта - сюрприз! - "с".